error about pd.read_hdf in Python: 'VLArray._read_array: Problems reading the array data.'
When I tried to read a h5 file in Python, I used this:
china_data = pd.read_hdf('stock_data.h5', key='data')

However, I got error like this:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HDF5ExtError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 china_data = pd.read_hdf('stock_data.h5', key='data')

File d:\software\mambaforge\envs\Alterithm\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py:452, in read_hdf(path_or_buf, key, mode, errors, where, start, stop, columns, iterator, chunksize, **kwargs)
    447                 raise ValueError(
    448                     "key must be provided when HDF5 "
    449                     "file contains multiple datasets."
    450                 )
    451         key = candidate_only_group._v_pathname
--> 452     return store.select(
    453         key,
    454         where=where,
    455         start=start,
    456         stop=stop,
    457         columns=columns,
    458         iterator=iterator,
    459         chunksize=chunksize,
    460         auto_close=auto_close,
    461     )
    462 except (ValueError, TypeError, LookupError):
    463     if not isinstance(path_or_buf, HDFStore):
    464         # if there is an error, close the store if we opened it.

File d:\software\mambaforge\envs\Alterithm\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py:906, in HDFStore.select(self, key, where, start, stop, columns, iterator, chunksize, auto_close)
    892 # create the iterator
    893 it = TableIterator(
    894     self,
    895     s,
   (...)
    903     auto_close=auto_close,
    904 )
--> 906 return it.get_result()

File d:\software\mambaforge\envs\Alterithm\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py:2029, in TableIterator.get_result(self, coordinates)
   2026     where = self.where
   2028 # directly return the result
-> 2029 results = self.func(self.start, self.stop, where)
   2030 self.close()
   2031 return results

File d:\software\mambaforge\envs\Alterithm\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py:890, in HDFStore.select.<locals>.func(_start, _stop, _where)
    889 def func(_start, _stop, _where):
--> 890     return s.read(start=_start, stop=_stop, where=_where, columns=columns)

File d:\software\mambaforge\envs\Alterithm\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py:3292, in BlockManagerFixed.read(self, where, columns, start, stop)
   3290 for i in range(self.nblocks):
   3291     blk_items = self.read_index(f"block{i}_items")
-> 3292     values = self.read_array(f"block{i}_values", start=_start, stop=_stop)
   3294     columns = items[items.get_indexer(blk_items)]
   3295     df = DataFrame(values.T, columns=columns, index=axes[1], copy=False)

File d:\software\mambaforge\envs\Alterithm\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py:2956, in GenericFixed.read_array(self, key, start, stop)
   2953 transposed = getattr(attrs, "transposed", False)
   2955 if isinstance(node, tables.VLArray):
-> 2956     ret = node[0][start:stop]
   2957 else:
   2958     dtype = _ensure_decoded(getattr(attrs, "value_type", None))

File d:\software\mambaforge\envs\Alterithm\lib\site-packages\tables\vlarray.py:662, in VLArray.__getitem__(self, key)
    660         key += self.nrows
    661     (start, stop, step) = self._process_range(key, key + 1, 1)
--> 662     return self.read(start, stop, step)[0]
    663 elif isinstance(key, slice):
    664     start, stop, step = self._process_range(
    665         key.start, key.stop, key.step)

File d:\software\mambaforge\envs\Alterithm\lib\site-packages\tables\vlarray.py:802, in VLArray.read(self, start, stop, step)
    800     listarr = []
    801 else:
--> 802     listarr = self._read_array(start, stop, step)
    804 atom = self.atom
    805 if not hasattr(atom, 'size'):  # it is a pseudo-atom

File d:\software\mambaforge\envs\Alterithm\lib\site-packages\tables\hdf5extension.pyx:2192, in tables.hdf5extension.VLArray._read_array()

HDF5ExtError: HDF5 error back trace

  File "D:\bld\hdf5_1701790448338\work\src\H5D.c", line 1061, in H5Dread
    can't synchronously read data
  File "D:\bld\hdf5_1701790448338\work\src\H5D.c", line 1008, in H5D__read_api_common
    can't read data
  File "D:\bld\hdf5_1701790448338\work\src\H5VLcallback.c", line 2092, in H5VL_dataset_read_direct
    dataset read failed
  File "D:\bld\hdf5_1701790448338\work\src\H5VLcallback.c", line 2048, in H5VL__dataset_read
    dataset read failed
  File "D:\bld\hdf5_1701790448338\work\src\H5VLnative_dataset.c", line 373, in H5VL__native_dataset_read
    can't read data
  File "D:\bld\hdf5_1701790448338\work\src\H5Dio.c", line 401, in H5D__read
    can't read data
  File "D:\bld\hdf5_1701790448338\work\src\H5Dchunk.c", line 2889, in H5D__chunk_read
    error looking up chunk address
  File "D:\bld\hdf5_1701790448338\work\src\H5Dchunk.c", line 3873, in H5D__chunk_lookup
    can't query chunk address
  File "D:\bld\hdf5_1701790448338\work\src\H5Dbtree.c", line 1029, in H5D__btree_idx_get_addr
    can't check for chunk in B-tree
  File "D:\bld\hdf5_1701790448338\work\src\H5B.c", line 314, in H5B_find
    unable to load B-tree node
  File "D:\bld\hdf5_1701790448338\work\src\H5AC.c", line 1277, in H5AC_protect
    H5C_protect() failed
  File "D:\bld\hdf5_1701790448338\work\src\H5Centry.c", line 3125, in H5C_protect
    can't load entry
  File "D:\bld\hdf5_1701790448338\work\src\H5Centry.c", line 1204, in H5C__load_entry
    Can't deserialize image
  File "D:\bld\hdf5_1701790448338\work\src\H5Bcache.c", line 162, in H5B__cache_deserialize
    wrong B-tree signature

End of HDF5 error back trace

VLArray._read_array: Problems reading the array data.

My packages version:
numpy 1.26.4
pandas 2.2.1
pytables 3.9.2
python 3.10.13

Many thanks!
